# In a MYSQL table with columns A, B, C and many rows how do you get a value from B where A=1 & C=1 if said value isn't also present where A=2 using PHP

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a table with millions of rows using PHP not SQL.

** to Select column B value from table where column A=1 & column C=1 if said value is not present wherever column A=2  in a MYSQL table **

In the example table the requested B value is 5.

I want to get a value from  column B with a column A value of 1 and column C value of 1 if this column B value is not also present  where column A value is 2.

Thanks.

```
Table
+-+-+-+
|A|B|C|
+-+-+-+
|1|3|0|
+-+-+-+
|1|6|0|
+-+-+-+
|1|5|1|
+-+-+-+
|2|3|1|
+-+-+-+
|2|4|1|
+-+-+-+
|3|3|0|
+-+-+-+
|1|3|1|
+-+-+-+

Select B where A=1,  C=1  and wherever A is not equal to 2. 

* 1st and 2nd row A=1 but C=0 so this is not answer, 
* 3rd row, both A and C are equal to 1 and B= 5 , since there is not B=5 where A=2 this is the answer. 
* 4th, 5th and 6th row are not right answer because A is not equal to 1
* 7th row is not an answer because B=3 is also present when A=2
```

Comment: Just to clarify;  select B if A=1 and C=1, if B not found select B if A=2. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Select B where A=1,  C=1  and wherever A is not equal to 2. 

* 1st and 2nd row A=1 but C=0 s this is not answer, 
* 3rd row, both A and C are equal to 1 and B= 5 , since there is no B=5 where A=2 this is the answer. 
* 4th, 5th and 6th row not right answer because A is not equal to 1

Comment: If I understand, your example would be more meaningful if there was a row `1,3,1` yet B=3 would not be included in the result set.

Comment: Thats correct. 1,3,1 would not be answer cause B=3 is present when A=2

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is add to your where clause to exclude the values of `B` that are the result of a subquery:

```
SELECT `B` FROM `my_table` WHERE `A`=1 AND `C`=1 AND `B` NOT IN (SELECT `B` FROM `my_table` WHERE `A`=2);
```

This just gets a list of the cases where B is found with A=2, and then excludes them from the main query.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. This is the solution I was after.